# How to generate graphs from lmbench results?

Tags: linux, performance, cache, benchmark

I need to use the lmbench benchmarking tool to get the system performance statistics.

I am able to execute and run the results. In the results folder this is a MakeFile with this information

```
# Makefile for lmbench results.`
# $Id$
#
# Usage: make [ LIST="aix/* sunos/* ..." ] [ what ]
#
# What to make:
#       stats                   Do statistics over a set of results
#       roff                    Print the ascii summaries into a roff file
# List of result files to process.  Defaults to everything.
LIST=  $(SCRIPTS)getlist $(LST)`
```

I am not clear on what to pass as the parameter for LIST nor am I able to create the graphs. Any clear steps on this would be helpful.